# SilverStripe 3.1 GridField file link is re-written with HTML Entities

Tags: hyperlink, silverstripe

I'm very new to Silverstripe (3.1). I am using it to collect applications from users. Each user uploads a file which later in the CMS somebody can download.
There is a has_one relationship for the file called 'Document.'
I want to link to that file inside a GridField. So after some searching I did the solution below - easy, and it works except for one problem.

The link does appear inside the correct column in the GridField but it has been converted through something like HTMLSpecialChars() and I can see all the HTML. For the life me I cannot figure how to stop it.
I would like to know where this conversion is taking place? 
and how can I circumvent it?

```
$submissionGrid = new GridField('submissions', 'Submissions', $submission, $config );

$submissionGrid->addDataFields(array(
        "Document" => function($row) {
            $link = '<a href="' . $row->Document()->getAbsoluteURL() . '">Download Document</a>';
            return $link;
        },
    ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close.

Instead of addDataFields(), have you tried setFieldFormatting on the configuration of your gridfield?

```
$submissionGrid = new GridField('submissions', 'Submissions', $submission, $config );
$config = $submissionGrid->getConfig();
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setFieldFormatting(array(
    "Document" => function($value, $item) {
        $link = '<a href="' . $item->Document()->getAbsoluteURL() . '">Download Document</a>';
        return $link;
    },
));
```

Depending on the fields available on the Submission Dataobject, if "Document" is something you are adding as a custom column to your gridfield, you will need to add it as well using setDisplayFields(). In this case, add this as well

```
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
    "Document" => "Link to document"
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two things. I did try setFieldFormatting but I found that any attempt to then add the Document field the the DiplayFields array resulted in "the method 'fortemplate' does not exist on 'File'." That said, your code looks like it has a higher probability of working than anything else I have seen today due to the fact that it has the arguments $value and $item. I hadn't seen those before. It still crashes though. Maybe what I need to do is actually add the custom field an then format it??? Sounds like crazy talk! Anyway I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

What actually worked:

I gave the right answer to jfbarrois for pointing me straight but thought I should post up the code that actually worked because it took me a while to find this answer.

It does have the inestimable advantage that it does actually work and a link is placed in a custom-formatted column in the GridField.

```
$config = GridFieldConfig_Base::create();

$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields($displayFields);
// Adding the custom named 'Download' column to the previously defined $displayFields
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(
    array_merge($displayFields, array(
            "Download" => "Link to document"
        )
    ));

// Set the field formatting on the custom column inserting the real data from the 'Document' File Object
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setFieldFormatting(array(
        "Download" => function($value, $item) {
            $link = '<a href="' . $item->Document()->getAbsoluteURL() . '">Download Document</a>';
            return $link;
        },
    ));

// Create the GridField
$submissionGrid = new GridField('submissions', 'Submissions', $submission, $config );
```